# Tensorflow: vectorize loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution

I have to vectorize a loop in Tensorflow.

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(3):
        res[i] += A[i - j + 1, j] * u[i - j + 1]
```

It's some kind of convolution with position dependent kernel.
I was said it might be done using tf.einsum, but I don't know how.

The only way I know is to use tf.while_loop, but I want something more elegant. Please, help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the loop over j is so small, you could do some tricks to "flip the loop around" and only vectorize the inner loop. That should be fast enough.

Specifically, your loop can be interchanged like this:

```
for j in range(3):
    for i in range(n):
        res[i] += A[i - j + 1, j] * u[i - j + 1]
```

And then we can vectorize the inner loop (writing out the zeros for clarity)

```
for j in range(3):
    res += A[0 - j + 1:n - j + 1, j] * u[0 - j + 1: n - j + 1]
```

Do note that for j = 2 the indices will become negative, which may indicate a mistake in your code.